# Getting Bike Lanes using Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, maps, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to write a query to get all bike lanes to display on a map for my project. I want to display all types of bike lanes(shared ,dedicated,tracks etc)

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “cycleway=*”

  // sharrow
  way["cycleway"="shared_lane"]({{bbox}} ) ;

  // CONVENTIONAL BICYCLE LANE
  // lane on both sides of the street
  way["cycleway"="lane"]({{bbox}});

  // lane on either side
  way["cycleway:left"]({{bbox}});
  way["cycleway:right"]({{bbox}});


  // dedicated bikeways
  way["highway"="cycleway"]({{bbox}});

  way["bicycle"="designated"]({{bbox}});



);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Am I missing some parameters because I am not getting the same map as open cycle maps. I understand that the open cycle maps is displaying cycling routes as well. So I added the parameter

```
relation["route"="bicycle"]({{bbox}});
```

But I am not very sure about what a relation is. Also it gives a lot of overlapping paths. Are all bile paths covered under a relation? Also from my understanding, this relation also has routes which would not necessarily go through a bike path. Coming back to my original question, are there any other parameters that I can add to my query to get all bike paths?

Comment: Duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486606/all-bike-lanes-using-overpass-turbo

Comment: Another duplicate post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/64879/get-all-bicycle-infrastructure-for-a-city

Comment: "But I am not very sure about what a relation is." - see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation  and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:route

Comment: "I am not getting the same map as open cycle maps" please give a specific example where this problem happens

Comment: Just when visually comparing the map for NYC, I am missing a few bike lanes, which gets me to think that I am missing some parameters in my query but can't figure out which

Answer (score 1):

You can check https://www.cyclosm.org/ for bicycle lanes. CycleOSM uses https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/blob/master/taginfo.json as the tags that get included.

For checking how it gets rendered:

- https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/blob/master/roads.mss
- https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/blob/master/views.sql

You can search for "bicycle" and figure it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **relation** in place of way.
It seems to replicate opencyclemap but best to check and modify as required.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “cycleway=*”

  // sharrow 
  relation["cycleway"="shared_lane"]({{bbox}} ) ;

  // CONVENTIONAL BICYCLE LANE
  // lane on both sides of the street 
  relation["cycleway"="lane"]({{bbox}});  

  // lane on either side 
  relation["cycleway:left"]({{bbox}});
  relation["cycleway:right"]({{bbox}});  


  // dedicated bikeways
  relation["highway"="cycleway"]({{bbox}});
  relation["bicycle"="designated"]({{bbox}});  
  
  // addition *route
  relation["route"="bicycle"]({{bbox}});


);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```